# Manually override the child using nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

I am currently writing a Nightwatch test to select a new document from a list. And I will need to be able to select the next in the list. Is there a way to manually override the child number that needs selecting?

For example the current selector being used is :

```
<ul class="dv-packdocs">
 <li class="dv-packdoc"<div class="icon-todo"></li>
 <li class="dv-packdoc"<div class="icon-todo"></li>
 <li class="dv-packdoc"<div class="icon-todo"></li>
 <li class="dv-packdoc"<div class="icon-todo"></li>
</ul>
```

and the test would be something like :

```
viewer.selectNewDocument([2])
```

would this select the second child under the `ul`?

Or would I have to specify each child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to dynamically find the appropriate child element (`li`) from a dynamical length list (*`ul`, where the list is populated based on user input, or other site actions*). Correct?

I see two scenarios with two different approaches:

**1.** **You have a set/fixed condition** (*way of identifying your target element*): for example, in your list, the second `li` would be targeted by the below command.

`viewer.selectNewDocument('ul.dv-packdocs li:nth-child(2)')` (*considering you are passing a complete selector to the `selectNewDocument` function*)

, or

`viewer.selectNewDocument(2)`, passing a `number` & form the selector inside the command (*if you care for aesthetics*):

```
selectNewDocument: function(index) {
  this.api.perform((done) => {
    // Click the second document in the list:
    let selector = `ul.dv-packdocs li:nth-child(${index})`;
    this.api.click(selector);
    done();
  });
  return this;  
},
```

Alternatively, if you would want the last document added, then you would have to issue a [elements](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/elements.html) call on the `ul` to retrieve the length of the list, then use that in the same way to determine which `li` you have to click: `viewer.selectNewDocument('ul.dv-packdocs li:nth-child('+length+')')` (*where `length` is the result of your `elements` call*).

---

**2.** **You don't have a fixed condition** (*I'll fill this up if the first part doesn't cover it, or later today, kinda slammed after the holidays*)

Hope it's what you were looking for! Cheers!

Comment: The first scenario, second solution was EXACTLY what I am looking for! Works absolutely perfectly! So I just needed to make the selection a function and define the child number as the number I am passing in from the test  so easy 

Comment: Yessir, that is correct! You are on the right path.